# I want to fetch more than 200 tweets.Can any one share an example of Spring Social Twitter Streaming Api? How to use streamingOperations() method?

Tags: spring, twitter, spring-social, twitter-streaming-api

I want to fetch more than 200 tweets.

Can any one share an example of Spring Social Twitter Streaming Api? How to use `streamingOperations()` method? I cannot find any example in the user documentation.